# Is it possible to hide a library dependency if it's a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a library A that uses library B. I want the user of A to use a templated class from B library. But A and B have different namespaces, is it possible to encapsulate/hide that class from B in A namespace?

I tried to use PIMPL but ... It's a template, so don't know exactly how can I do it.

For reference the class that I want to encapsulate in my library is:

```
namespace anax {
template <typename T>
class Component : public BaseComponent
{
public:

    static detail::TypeId GetTypeId()
    {
        return detail::ClassTypeId<BaseComponent>::GetTypeId<T>();
    }
};

}
```

So the users of A, have to do for example:

```
   class Position: public anax::Component<Position>
   {
       float x,y,z;
   }
```

What I'm asking exactly is if it's possible to encapsulate/hide this anax::Component class inside my namespace like this:

```
   class Position: public myAnamespace::Component<Position>
   {
       float x,y,z;
   }
```

Comment: What about a using-directive?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
namespace myAnamespace{

    template<class Position>
    using Component = anax::Component<Position>;
}
```

Or, in pre-C++11,

```
namespace myAnamespace{

    template<class Position>
    struct Component
    {
         typedef anax::Component<Position> type;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think I'm searching something like that. But.. the users of A would be able to use anax::Component because it will be included too. I think I can't predeclare anax::Component if it's a template, I'm wrong?

Comment: You're probably right. To the best of my knowledge, you can't really do a full PIMPL-like solution with templates, for the reason you stated.

Comment: Maybe one solution will be to make a cmake option to change the namespace of the entire anax library to match mine (A namespace). I don't know if this is something that people do when dealing with templates classes in libraries..

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace anax
{
  class Component
  {
  };
};

namespace b
{
  using namespace anax;
  class Position : public Component
  {
  };
};
```